# Table Creation PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hi everyone im learning phpmyadmin along with some php scripting.
I need some help making the correct tables for the "phonebook" database of mine.

Here is the code for the members:

```
mysql_select_db ("phonebook"); 

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sqlQuery="insert into members  values(null,'$username' ,'$password' )" ;
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);  

include('index.php');
```

My question is how do i go about building the table and what fields do i create for it? thank you so much :D

Comment: If you're starting to learn PHP, please **don't** learn the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Instead invest your time learning PDO. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information.

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin.Under 'phonebook' database create a table members which has 3  columns ie. id,username,password. id wil have data type of int and username,password will have datatype of varchar.

Then go for the below insert query :

"INSERT INTO `members  `(`id`,`username`,`password`) VALUES (' ','".$username,'".$password."')";

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a table in your database to store the information

You can use this query. First go to phpmyadmin -> select your database and you have a tab that says SQL, open this tab and paste this query

```
CREATE TABLE `phonebook` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Next you will need to make a connection to your database is your script. As a begginer you can do this like this.

```
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
```

after the connection you will need a form. Do it this way.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    Phone:<input type='text' name='phone'><br>
    Username:<input type='text' name='username'><br>
    Password:<input type='password' name='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='save'>
</form>
```

after the form is submited you will need to take the data and insert to the DB

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['phone']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['password']);

    $sqlQuery = "insert into members (phone, username, password) values('$phone','$username','$password')" ;
    $result  =  mysqli_query($sqlQuery);
    if(!$result){
        echo mysqli_error();
    }

}
```

You have many many examples online just read them :)

Comment: is it possible to remove the registration all together and set only 1 or 2 users to be able to login? like pre defined username and password because we wont be adding anymore users anyway.

Comment: To access this form you have to login to a system or it is available to all?

Comment: i would like to remove the registration form and leave the login form that i have already i just want to set only 2 people to be able to login and no option to add more. i can send you my files if you wish to have alook sir.

Comment: you can use many solutions for }this. The best way is to use a session to track every user, Lets say if($_SESSION['rafael']){ then allow this form}, or you use multiple computers you can track the with the ip address if the ip is 192.168.1.1 then allow the form

Comment: Just send me a link of your code and i will check it